# Is there any documentation on "build_matrix" function in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a LSTM model for a time series problem, and I came across a great article:

https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2018-06-25-sunspots-lstm/

There is a part where the authors used "build_matrix" to build a windowed matrix, for example:

```r
train_matrix <-
  build_matrix(train_vals, n_timesteps + n_predictions)
```

I'd like to ask if any one has used this function before? Or if you have any good references for this function?

I have tried "?build_matrix" and "??build_matrix" in R-Studio and I've also searched online, but to no avail. It is an interesting and helpful function by looking at the outcome, and so I'm interested to understand how it works in R. Any help would be much appreciated!

To give you more information, I'm going to show some results from "build_matrix" here and compare it with function "matrix":

```r
build_matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
[5,]    5    6    7
[6,]    6    7    8
```

Compare to:

```r
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),2,4)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    2    4    6    8
```

This is my first question on Stackoverflow. Please pardon me if I asked the question at the wrong place or it's not phrased clearly. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The blog post you linked to *defines the function itself*. There’s no documentation but source code is right there, and consists of only two lines of code.

Comment: Thank you Konrad for your prompt reply! Yes, you are right! How could I miss that......